# Why am I facing this error? - java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf

I am creating a simple Laptop-info form using JSF and Hibernate in [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA). When I execute my project then I face this error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:667)
```

Here I list the required files and directory structure.

1. LaptopDAO.java

   ```
    package Dao;

    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.Transaction;
    import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
    import pojo.Laptop;
    import util.HibernateUtil;

    public class LaptopDAO {

        public void SaveLaptop(Laptop laptop)
        {
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(laptop);
            t.commit();
            session.close();
        }
    }
   ```
2. Laptop.hbm.xml

   ```xml
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
   <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
       "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
       "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

   <hibernate-mapping>
       <class name="pojo.Laptop" table="laptopdb">
           <id name="id"><generator class="increment"></generator></id>
           <property name="company">
               <column name="laptopcompany"></column>
           </property>
           <property name="model">
               <column name="laptopmodel"></column>
           </property>
           <property name="ram">
               <column name="laptopram"></column>
           </property>
           <property name="hd">
               <column name="laptophd"></column>
           </property>
       </class>
   </hibernate-mapping>
   ```
3. Class *LaptopBean*

   ```
    package LaptopMBean;

    import Dao.LaptopDAO;
    import pojo.Laptop;
    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    @ManagedBean(name = "laptopBean")

    public class LaptopBean {
        Laptop l;

        public LaptopBean()
        {
            l = new Laptop();
        }

        public Laptop getL()
        {
            return l;
        }

        public void setL(Laptop l)
        {
            this.l = l;
        }

        public void savetoDB()
        {
            LaptopDAO ld = new LaptopDAO();
            ld.SaveLaptop(l);
            System.out.print("Success");
        }
    }
   ```
4. Class *Laptop*

   ```
    package pojo;

    public class Laptop {
        int id;
        String company;
        String model;
        String ram;
        String hd;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getCompany() {
            return company;
        }

        public void setCompany(String company) {
            this.company = company;
        }

        public String getModel() {
            return model;
        }

        public void setModel(String model) {
            this.model = model;
        }

        public String getRam() {
            return ram;
        }

        public void setRam(String ram) {
            this.ram = ram;
        }

        public String getHd() {
            return hd;
        }

        public void setHd(String hd) {
            this.hd = hd;
        }
    }
   ```
5. Class *HibernateUtil*

   ```
    package util;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

    public class HibernateUtil
    {
        private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

        public static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory()
        {
            try
            {
                return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            }
            catch (Throwable ex)
            {
                System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed. " + ex);
                throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
            }
        }

        public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
        {
            return sessionFactory;
        }
    }
   ```
6. File *hibernate.cfg.xml*

   ```xml
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
   <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
       "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
       "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
   <hibernate-configuration>
       <session-factory>
           <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
           <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/laptop</property>
           <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
           <property name="connection.username">root</property>
           <property name="connection.password">admin</property>
           <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

           <mapping resource="hbm/laptop.hbm.xml"/>
       </session-factory>
   </hibernate-configuration>
   ```
7. StackTrace

   ```
   23:44:51,700 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (default
   task-4) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.3.Final
   23:44:52,080 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (default task-4) HHH000412:
   Hibernate Core {5.4.0.Final}
   23:44:52,084 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (default task-4)
   HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
   23:44:52,091 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4) Initial SessionFactory creation
   failed.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
   net/bytebuddy/NamingStrategy$SuffixingRandom$BaseNameResolver
   23:44:52,092 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle]
   (default task-4) #{laptopBean.savetoDB()}:
   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: javax.faces.FacesException: #
   {laptopBean.savetoDB()}:
   ```

I have added all libraries. How can I find out what the problem is?

Comment: Can you please go ahead and post the whole stracktrace? The answer to the problem you're having could be found by inspecting it.

Comment: @Aris_Kortex Stacktrace added.

Comment: Hm as you can see by the stacktrace you just posted, the application fails due to this error `failed.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
net/bytebuddy/NamingStrategy$SuffixingRandom$BaseNameResolver`. Make sure that your jars are not corrupted. Trying cleaning them from maven's cachec and rebuild the application.

Comment: JAR's are up-to-date and i clean cache but still facing same issue. :( @Aris_Kortex

Comment: Which tutorial are you using? You have some very ancient dtd locations. And instead of hibernate directly, it is more common nowadays to use JPA(2.1) with e.g. Hibernate as the implementation. And using XML files for mapping entities can nowadays be done by adding annotations (like with @ManagedBean) which by itself is also already deprecated and superseeded by using CDI managed beans. Please look at https://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info for a more modern tutorial. Also check http://jsf.zeef.com/